# Add/Subtract multiple ID fields in SQL table

Tags: sql

*PrestaShop Question*

Hello. I wanted to know if it was possible to add/subtract multiple ID fields in a SQL table? What statement could I use?

(STATEMENT) FROM `example_table`.`ps_product` WHERE `ps_category`.`id_category` < 79;

Comment: What do you mean by "add/subtract multiple ID fields"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you mean `field1 + field2 + field3` then yes its possible.  I am a little unclear from your question, could you provide your SQL attempt at solving the problem and then everyone can help you get to a working solution.

Comment: I need to decrement a id_category value by 1 for each id_category above 79 within the id_category column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment on the question:

> I need to decrement a id_category value by 1 for each id_category above 79 within the id_category column

You can perform a simple decrement in an `UPDATE` statement.  Something like this might work:

```
UPDATE
  example_table
SET
  id_category = id_category - 1
WHERE
  id_category > 79
```

This would find every record in the `example_table` table where `id_category` is greater than 79 and update each such record to decrement `id_category` by 1.

Do be careful with something like this.  I have two potential concerns worth noting here:

1. If you have an `id_category` of 79 and one of 80 before this process, you'll have two of 79 after this process.  The `> 79` clause will no longer find the same record set.  I don't know if this is a problem in the overall space of what you're doing, but it's worth considering logically.
2. If `id_category` is the *identifier* for these records then don't do this.  At all.  Identifiers shouldn't be changed because they should uniquely and forever *identify* the record.